# Phone gap is synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: cordova

I am using phonegap for first time and wants to know whether the Phonegap is synchronous or asynchronous.
Or it is both synchronous and asynchronous?

Comment: Normally asynchronous, but if I say _only_ asynchronous I'm sure someone will find a counter example :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

When you build applications with Phonegap, you're just using plain old HTML, CSS, and Javascript. Good Javascript is asynchronous, but it's definitely possible to write synchronous code as well.

Comment: Most of the Phonegap functions are asynchronous